# Knot Theory: Where does the Celtic Five Fold Fit?

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

I get that it's five *unknots* like the three borromean rings (L6a4 in the knot Atlas), but I couldn't find any knot theory/topological discussion anywhere on it. The picture below depicts one in the middle.

[image]

Comment: I entered the link in Snappy and it did not identify it.  I would note that it is not a Brunnian Ring, which is the special property that the Borromean Rings have.  Also, the Borromean rings have very nice hyperbolic geometry, whereas this link does not seem to be so nice.  Was there something in particular you are looking for?

Comment: There's another version of the five fold, too, where instead of linking number $1$, the components have linking number $0$. http://mythologian.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Five-Fold-Symbol-Ancient-Celtic-Symbols-and-Their-Meanings.jpg

Comment: Kyle I appreciate the variant! It looks identical except the very center lacks the overlap.